# JavaFX Task thread apparently not running simultaneously

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I have been trying to put a Loading Scene between scenes and my idea was the following:

1. Start a thread to create the desired scene;
2. The method to create the scene also sets the created scene to the Scene attribute of the class;
3. While the thread is running, the loading scene is being created and set.
4. When the thread is done, the scene is set to the desired scene.

Apparently the whole Loading scene is ignored and the desired scene is just set straightfoward. My bet is that the thread is not working simultaneously.

Here is the task part and relevant attributes.

```
private Stage pokeWindow = new Stage();
    private Scene currentScene;
    private boolean sceneReady = false;
    private String targetScene;
    private int genericInt;

    private final Task setGenericScene = new Task(){
        @Override
        protected Object call() throws Exception {
           sceneReady = false;

        if(targetScene.equals("summaryScene")){
            setSummaryScene(genericInt);
            sceneReady = true;
        }

        return null;
        }  
    };
```

Here is the loading scene.

```
public void setLoadingScene(){
       Thread loadScreen = new Thread(setGenericScene);
        loadScreen.start();


        if(!sceneReady){
        GridPane background = new GridPane();
        BackgroundImage loadingBG = new BackgroundImage(new Image((new File("src/resources/tiles/pokedexfullbg.png")).toURI().toString()), BackgroundRepeat.REPEAT, BackgroundRepeat.REPEAT, BackgroundPosition.DEFAULT, BackgroundSize.DEFAULT);
        background.setBackground(new Background(loadingBG));

    [...]
    [more javafx code regarding the loading scene]

    Scene loadingScene = new Scene(background, 512, 416);
        this.pokeWindow.setScene(loadingScene);

        animation1.play();
        animation2.play();
        animation3.play();
        animation4.play();
        animation5.play();
        animation6.play();
        animation7.play();
        animation8.play();

        while(!sceneReady){}
        }

        this.pokeWindow.setScene(currentScene);
    }
```

Comment: What up with `while(!sceneReady){}`? You need to look up how to do something once a `Task` is finished. `task.setOnSucceeded()`.

Comment: You're using a non-`volatile` variable from multiple threads; there's no guarantee updates to it from one thread will be seen by another. Besides that, as Sedrick mentions, you shouldn't be busy waiting on a `boolean` variable to know when a `Task` completes. This will cause the FX thread to "freeze" inside the `while` loop (possibly indefinitely due to the non-volatility issue).

Comment: You're blocking the application thread, possibly with an infinite loop (even if `targetScene` equals `"summaryScene"`). Starting multiple animations in parallel may indicate that you do not understand that `play` only schedules repeated updates caused by the animation; it does not block until the animation finishes. As Sedrick noted it would be best to use `onSucceeded` for the task and I recommend using a `Task<Parent>` and returning the content that's supposed to be shown in the scene from the `Task.call` method.

Comment: In general, using a `Task` means that you want it to do something in another thread and then return an object as a result, then pass this result to JavaFX Application thread for consumption. If you are not going to return a result, and you are doing your own synchronization, then a `new Thread(Runnable)` would have done the same thing. In this case, the only thing that must be done in JavaFX Application Thread is `Stage.setScene()` (as far as I know), so your `Task` can return either a `Parent` or a `Scene`.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.